# recursive spark input stopped working on EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I had a Spark-EMR job which processed data from a s3 location. The input folder had recursively many folders.

I was using sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true") property to handle the recursive input.

Till the last couple of days, it was working fine but suddenly it has stopped working i dont know why, giving FileNotFoundException

(....is a directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.open(NativeS3FileSystem.java:627)....)

I am using s3n as the filesystem. 
Any pointers?

EMR version : emr-5.7.0

Comment: Is it possible that your files is being deleted after spark run 'ls' on the folder ? 'ls' are very slow in S3 relatively  to hdfs